# How to replace a char that is not lead by another char

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a JavaScript Regular Expression that will replace `i` in `sin(i/20*i)` but not in the `i` in `sin`. Using `(\W)i` will always give me `(i` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace

```
\bi\b
```

which will require `i` to stand alone (or at least not in a string of alphanumeric characters and underscores). The `\b` is a zero-width assertion, as it matches a *position between characters*, so you don't capture more than you need.

The usual cautions apply. With only a single example it's hard to give a good solution that works for whatever data you want to throw it at. Adapt accordingly.